# New column after third row

Tags: reactjs

I'm mapping table from JSON in my React project. I want a specific table, to showing names like this:

```
---------------------------------------
||name[0] |name[1] ||name[6] |name[7]||
||name[2] |name[3] ||name[8] |name[9]||
||name[4] |name[5] ||name[10] |name[11]||
---------------------------------------
```

I've try maping this table like this, but it doesn't work.

```
{data11.map((user, index) => {
  const { name } = user;
  return (
    {(index % 2 === 1) > (<tr id={index}>) : null }
      <td>{name}</td>
    {(index % 2 === 0) > (</tr>) : null }
  );
  })  
}
```

How could I make a new row after second data and afert three rows make new column?

Comment: Could you cut your list in half and create 2 tables and use styling to achieve this instead?